# How best to populate a subordinate numeric key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables: Items and Defects.

Each defect relates to one (and only one) item.

The PK for Items is an identity column (ItemID), which appears as a FK column in Defects, to relate the two tables.

The PK for Defects is an identity column (DefectID).

However there is also a subordinate numeric key in Defects called RefNo, which must be populated by a sequential number *per ItemID*, thus:

Defects

```
DefectID   ItemID    RefNo
1          1         1 
2          1         2
3          1         3
4          2         1
5          2         2
6          3         1
7          4         1
8          3         2
9          1         4
```

What's the best way to populate the Ref column?

Currently the code I inherited accomplishes this in the front end which is obviously A Bad Idea.

I am starting to code an insert trigger (SQL Server 2008-R2) but wonder about atomicity and the need to potentially update more than one row when the trigger is called - and the likelihood of simultaneous inserts by different users to try and insert the same RefNo.

[Edit]

I'm maintaining an existing database and removing the RefNo column and repacing it with a value calculated on the fly is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER as below to generate your refno-

```
WITH your_table(DefectID,ItemID,RefNo)
AS
(
SELECT 1,1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,2,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,2,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,3,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 7,4,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 8,3,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 9,1,4
)

SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY DefectID) AS RefNo_new
FROM your_table
order by 2,1
```

Output-

```
DefectID    ItemID  RefNo   RefNo_new
1           1       1       1
2           1       2       2
3           1       3       3
9           1       4       4
4           2       1       1
5           2       2       2
6           3       1       1
8           3       2       2
7           4       1       1
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you are suggesting here. Are you saying the entire column is not required as it could be generated on the fly? If so that doesn't really answer my question as I need to modify an existing database, and removing the column isn't an option. I'll amend my question to state this. Or are you suggesting I could use this to work out the next number to add in the RefNo column? If so, how?